# How can I find the equivalent resistance of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, thevenin

I'm trying to find the Norton Equivalent circuit using Norton's Theorem for the circuit below. Since I need to find the Norton Resistance, I removed all the sources from the circuit. The problem is, I can't find the equivalent resistance because I don't know what to do with the 10kΩ resistance. I would appreciate it if I can get an explanation on what I should do. Also, what should come to mind when trying to find equivalent resistance of complicated circuits? Thanks.

### Circuit for Finding Norton Equivalent

[image]

### Circuit for Finding Norton Resistance

[image]

Comment: Remove 10kohm resistance as it is shorted ,and for complicated circuits generally we apply a voltage or current source (here between ab) and measure current through it or voltage across it (source) and then V/I gives your equivalent resistance

Comment: I just realized, would a source conversion for the 10mA current source solve the problem? But, if I do that we will get the same circuit for finding the equivalent resistance. So, I should just remove it.

Comment: The 10k is shorted so the equivalent resistance is 5k||15k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Norton Resistance**

You already did the essential steps, e.g. remove load, replace voltage and current sources with short and open circuits respectively.

$$R_{norton}=5k\Omega||15k\Omega=3.75k\Omega$$

**Norton Current**

Simplify the circuit by converting current to voltage sources:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7zwir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Calculate the voltage at the load:

$$V_{a,b}=30V-\dfrac{45V}{20k\Omega}\cdot15k\Omega = -3.75V$$

Calculating the norton current:

$$I_{norton}=\dfrac{-3.75V}{3.75k\Omega}=-1mA$$

Redrawing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQTP1J.png)</sup>